# Display text based on multiple checkbox selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I'm currently trying to figure out how to display predefined texts based on checkbox selections (multiple) in Google Sheets.

Example:

```
Checkbox 1 True
Checkbox 2
Checkbox 3 True
```

Predefined answers:

```
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer 3
```

Result:

- Displaying the strings of Answer 1 + Answer 3 in a textbox.
- If Checkbox 2+3 are checked, text of answer 2+3 should be shown inside a textbox.

Any idea how to make that happen?

Another exmaple in the picture:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYuoY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=textjoin(char(10),,arrayformula(vlookup(filter( C1:C6, A1:A6=true, left(C1:C6,1)=A15),A8:B13,2,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I've enclosed a picture to show what I'm trying to do. Would that be somehow possible?

Comment: I edited my answer to meet your expectations!

Comment: First of all, thank you very much!!! I tried it out and it works fine for this example.

But if I try to change the result criteria from "A" to "B", it won't show me the result. As you can see in my enclosed picture, there are three different categories available (A,B and C) .... If try to find a result for the ticked "B's" within a list of A's and B's, the formula won't work anymore....  Looking at my example, the formula for 'B' should display B1+B2. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Tried adding an additional condition after A1:A3=true --> + C1:C3=(Left("B"))  ... but sadly it won't work. (having more answers linked to "B" down below.

Comment: ok, I have updated my answer!

Comment: Hey there, I've figured it out myself before checking your answer now. Thank you very much for your help! Works perfectly fine :) I owe you a drink ;) You saved my day!!!

Comment: Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do the same thing with onedit trigger

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("onEdit");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1) {
    sh.getRange('D1').setValue(sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2).getValues().filter(r => r[0]).map(r => r[1]).join(','));
  }
}
```

The ouput is the string in col2 where col1 is truthy

Comment: I've enclosed a picture to show what I'm trying to do. Would that be somehow possible?

Comment: The image in the other question makes more sense to me.